# Can a Certificate Authority associated with Active Directory publish a client certificate to a browser?

Tags: web-browser, client-side, active-directory

Can I use some integration of Windows Active Directory and a Certificate Authority to embed a client certificate in a browser that will be trusted by a server?

I have a private domain and control over who can login. Is it reasonably possible and secure to have, upon login, a client-side cert installed such that the browser can take advantage of it and provide it when logging into specific sites (also on my network).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Group Policy to install the certificate on the client machines.  You will need to bind the certificate to your site through IIS/Apache to complete the process.  Keep in mind that you will need to ensure that your internal CA is trusted by your internal clients.

I think this is in fact reasonably secure, and one of the use cases that [Certificate Services](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779149%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) was designed to accommodate.

Here is a link from MSDN detailing the specifics of implementing such a system: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727098.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the insightful answer and links. Appreciate it.